# Can variable type in Crystal lang be restricted to classes that inherit from one class

Tags: crystal-lang

I mean:

```
class Foo; end
class Bar < Foo; end
class Cux < Foo; end
```

Is it possible to restrict type of the variable to classes inheriting from `Foo` without unions, something like `x : Foo+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using a type restriction?

```
@x : Foo
```

Comment: Weird, previously on carc.in I tried that - and it raised of type mismatch. Now it works. BTW thanks for your great job on Crystal! How's new compiler going?

Comment: We abandoned the new compiler for now. We'll start by making the current compiler have the semantics we want. Once that is done we won't be breaking any more code and we can focus (slowly) on optimizing the compiler or maybe rewriting it from scratch, or rewrite some sub-systems.